# Mumble Channels

Tags: networking, 13.04, mumble

I am running the last version of mumble and I am unable to connect myself to one particular mumble server. it was first setup with the default port 64738 then changed to 66 which allow me now to see the number of users and the ping from this server.

The problem is that on my ISP connection at home I can't see anything else than Root. People see me and can talk to me but I can't hear them and I can't speak with them

I have tried many but I still don't it why it doesn't work..... I have tried with my cellphone and it worked... shared it with my computer it worked... so it gotta be something with my ISP or my network.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Raring there seems to be an odd connection issue with mumble.

For me the current work around seems to be:
1. Ensure your audio settings are how you want them
2. Connect initially as normal
3. This seems to work but you get no channel listing
4. Open a terminal, type killall mumble
5. Reopen mumble
6. Connect and now you should see your channels

Comment: well in my case it was a lot simple than that. I have noticed that the problem in this case was my ISP. I am with Bell and Bell have issues with their DNS server and this server. So I took a VPN server and connected myself to it. So now I can see all the channels.